# Why does my wii not read disc any more?

Tags: nintendo-wii

The disc are brand new, and it simply refuses to read a disc. If it reads a disc and I play it for about 5 seconds, it then says "a rare error occured please remove disc and turn off console" Why?

Comment: Does it do this with *every* disc?  Or just certain ones?

Comment: Is the *wii* brand new?

Comment: A similar sounding issue happened to my wii a while back. This issue was that the actual laser inside the system, the one used to read disks, had become scratched or broken or something along those lines. As it turns out the cost of replacing this laser is more than simply purchasing a new wii. So I waited and bought a wii-u instead. I would note that my wii was several years old, one of the originals I stood in line for when they came out. If your wii is brand new it may be some other issue.

Comment: @AdamP Comment good enough to be an answer... I am just having a hard time upvoting the one that mentions roaches inside the wii...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a laser issue. If a simple cleaning kit doesn't work, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This could be pretty much anything (well, almost). I've heard of defect disc drives, roaches inside the console, etc.

If you know someone with the needed experience and qualifications, get them to open the console and check ist insides. If you're still under warranty, just get it replaced instead.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a brand new disc isn't being read it's 2 things

1. The laser is broken and you need to get it replaced
2. **OR** There is dust inside your Wii and you have to either open it up or get the laser cleaning tools